# sqoop import free form query error

Tags: forms, import, sqoop

I'm noticing a strange issue with sqoop import. The data I'm trying to import is in the following form in MySQL DB:

```
<a1, a2, a3, d1, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8>
```

where a1, a2,..., a8 are of varchar type and d1 is timestamp type. Due to normalization of data, I had to do JOIN multiple tables in order to get these columns - something like the following:

```
SELECT t1.a1, t2.a2....... from table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.t2_id = t2.id ........... WHERE <some condition>
```

Initially I started out with a view like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT t1.a1, t2.a2....... from table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.t2_id = t2.id ........... WHERE <some condition>
```

sqoop command to import using this view as follows:

```
sqoop import --connect [jdbc url] --username [user] --password [password] --table my_view --target-dir my_dir --split-by a5 --mysql-delimiters --verbose --boundary-query 'SELECT min(a5), max(a5) from t5'
```

This works fine. Since MySQL view is not as optimized as one would like, I wanted to use raw SQL to see if it results in improved performance. To test this, I used the free form query instead:

```
sqoop import --connect [jdbc url] --username [user] --password [password] --query "SELECT t1.a1, t2.a2....... from table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.t2_id = t2.id ............ WHERE <some condition> AND \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir my_dir --split-by a5 --mysql-delimiters --verbose --boundary-query 'SELECT min(a5), max(a5) from t5'
```

So in this case --query parameter effectively has the view definition SELECT statement plus $CONDITIONS as required by sqoop. However, this doesn't work. sqoop imports half the records and fails with the following strange error:

```
13/09/27 20:28:10 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201309130032_0122_m_000000_2,  Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext.nextKeyValue(MapContext.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at    org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Value 'xxxxxx' can not be represented as     java.sql.Timestamp
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getTimestampFast(ResultSetRow.java:1102)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.BufferRow.getTimestampFast(BufferRow.java:576)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestampInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:6592)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:6192)
    at org.apache.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readTimestamp(JdbcWritableBridge.java:111)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readTimestamp(JdbcWritableBridge.java:83)
    at QueryResult.readFields(QueryResult.java:156)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:245)
    ... 11 more
```

As far as I can tell, sqoop is trying to interpret some other column (a3) value as a timestamp and that conversion fails since it's just a string and not a date type. I should also mention that some of our data is bad - we have newline's and tabs in some fields where they are not supposed to be but the date field does have valid values - I even tried using REPLACE function in MySQL to get rid of these but it's of no avail.

Given that the data is the same and the same SELECT statement is being used in either case, I expected the outcome to be the same (i.e., the same number of records returned by the SELECT is imported to HDFS).

Has any one seen this behavior before? Any ideas on how this issue can be addressed?

Comment: When you answer your own question you should provide it as an answer, then accept your own answer. (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).  This way your question will be marked as resolved.

Comment: I didn't realize I could answer my own question. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried executing the same command with different MySQL driver versions - while the same error was happening in all cases, the message was a bit more clear this time:

```
13/10/21 22:19:18 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201309130032_0308_m_000000_0,   Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
    at   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:265)
    at  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext.nextKeyValue(MapContext.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at  org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 7 to TIMESTAMP.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getTimestampFromBytes(ResultSet.java:6886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getTimestampInternal(ResultSet.java:6921)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getTimestamp(ResultSet.java:6245)
    at org.apache.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readTimestamp(JdbcWritableBridge.java:111)
    at  com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readTimestamp(JdbcWritableBridge.java:83)
    at QueryResult.readFields(QueryResult.java:156)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db
```

So the basic issue is that the value of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' date is stored in our db but can't be handled by the driver (I have tried several versions and none of them work). When using the raw sql with free form query option in sqoop, the driver tries to convert this date to a date object which fails resulting in the above error. Note that this doesn't happen if the same date value is extracted using a view - it appears that the driver doesn't try to convert this value into a date object in this case. For whatever reason, MySQL driver and server seem to be out of sync for handling invalid dates.

From [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html):

```
As of 5.0.2, the server requires that month and day values be legal, and not merely in   the range 1 to 12 and 1 to 31, respectively. With strict mode disabled, invalid dates such   as '2004-04-31' are converted to '0000-00-00' and a warning is generated. With strict mode   enabled, invalid dates generate an error.
```

Our legacy db server had strict mode disabled and whenever a legacy app tries to insert an invalid date (such as '2004-04-31'), it's converted to '0000-00-00' and this can't be handled by the driver as mentioned above for the raw sql case. Once these records are removed with a filter in the where clause, sqoop import works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this JDBC URL in your sqoop command

jdbc:mysql://yourserver:3306/yourdatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull

This work for me